# errors C2672 and C2784 in porting code from Linux and MacOS to Visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, visual-c++

**block_sparrse_matrix.h**

```
#include "ldl_decomposition.h"
SMVS_NAMESPACE_BEGIN

template<int N>
void
BlockSparseMatrix<N>::invert_blocks_inplace(void)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < this->values.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::array<double, N * N> b = values[i];
        ldl_inverse(b.begin(), N);
        bool nancheck = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < N * N; ++i)
            if (std::isnan(b[i]))
                nancheck = true;
        if(nancheck)
            continue;
        values[i] = b;
    }
}
```

**ldl_decomposition.h**

```
SMVS_NAMESPACE_BEGIN
template<typename T>
void
ldl_inverse(T * A, int const size)
{
    T * L = new T[size * size];
    T * D = new T[size];
    std::fill(L, L + size * size, 0.0);
    std::fill(D, D + size, 0.0);

    /* Factorize A into LDL^T */
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
    {
        D[j] = A[j * size + j];
        L[j * size + j] = 1.0;
        for (int k = 0 ; k < j; ++k)
            D[j] -= (L[j * size + k] * L[j * size + k]) * D[k];

        if (D[j] == 0.0)
            return;

        for (int i = j+1; i < size; ++i)
        {
            L[i * size + j] = A[i * size + j];
            for (int k = 0 ; k < j; ++k)
                L[i * size + j] -= L[i * size + k] * D[k] * L[j * size + k];
            L[i * size + j] /= D[j];
        }
    }

    /* Invert L */
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        for (int j = i+1; j < size; ++j)
        {
            T sum(0);
            for (int k = i ; k < j; ++k)
                sum -= L[j * size + k] * L[k * size + i];
            L[j * size + i] = sum;
        }

    /* Invert D */
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        D[i] = 1.0 / D[i];

    /* Combine Matrices */
    combine_ldl(L, D, size, A);

    /* Cleanup memory */
    delete[] L;
    delete[] D;
}
```

I want to make it work on Windows, but it is error.

```
Error C2672 'ldl_inverse': no matching overloaded function found 
(compiling source file E:\mve\libs\smvsrecon\gauss_newton_step.cc)

Error C2784 'void smvs::ldl_inverse(T *,const int)': could not deduce 
template argument for 'T *' from 'std::_Array_iterator<_Ty,16>'
```

Comment: Also see [Compiler Error C2784](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wf867f8f.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: `ldl_inverse` takes a pointer; you are passing an iterator. An implementation may legally make `std::array<T>::iterator` a simple typedef for `T*`, but it doesn't have to. Your code therefore relies on internal implementation details - no surprise it breaks when ported to a different implementation. Make it `ldl_inverse(b.data(), N);`

Comment: thx! `ldl_inverse(b.data(), N);` is compiled!